# Wpf Adorner Class not found

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm simply trying to create a custom `Adorner`...

```
  using System;
  using System.Windows.Documents; 
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows;

  public class BlockAdorner : Adorner
  {
    public BlockAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) :
      base(adornedElement)
  {
```

Even this fails, because "`Adorner` is a namespace but used like a type"

My Project has a reference to `PresentationFramework` (4.0.0.0)

Also my VS recognized `AdornerLayer` and `AdornerDecorator` as classes and jumps to `PresentationFramework` when I click on show Definition. Also I can see the MetaInfo of `Adorner` in that dll. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried fully qualifying it: System.Windows.Documents.Adorner - do you have a namespace in your application called "Adorner"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried fully qualifying it:

```
System.Windows.Documents.Adorner
```

do you have a namespace in your application called "Adorner"?